# symfony2: two authentication provider

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I have two separate authentication form. One for admin and another for user. But, when I authenticate from the both login page, it is handle by AdminUser Repository. In case of client authentication, it should be handle by User.Its not happening. What am I missing in the configuration ???

I also get this error if I did not add ESSUserBundle in default orm.

***Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMException' with message 'Unknown Entity namespace alias 'ESSUserBundle'.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\essweb\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\ORMException.php on line 236***

Security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        ESS\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
            algorithm: sha512
            encode-as-base64: true
            iterations: 1

        ESS\AdminUserBundle\Entity\AdminUser:
            algorithm: sha512
            encode-as-base64: true
            iterations: 1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        admin_area:
            entity: {class: ESSAdminUserBundle:AdminUser }

        company_area:
            entity: {class: ESSUserBundle:User, property: username}

firewalls:
        admin_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  /admin
                check_path:  /admin/login_check
                default_target_path: /admin/dashboard
                failure_path: /admin

            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /admin  

        company_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path: login_check
                default_target_path: /main/dashboard
                failure_path: /

            logout:
                path:   /main/logout
                target: /login
```

**Config.yml**

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    #auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:

                ESSCompanyBundle: ~
                ESSAdminUserBundle: ~

        client:
            connection: client
            mappings:
                ESSUserBundle: ~
```

Comment: What is the login_check url? Cause you use for normal login a route name called login_check not a path

Comment: login_check is default path for authentication of symfony framework...I remove it from above because it might bring confusion.

Comment: Without / that point to a route name, and this is why I'm asking, because every other config value is a path, not a route name and for admin, you used also a path. What is the value for login_check route?